# Should I run a linear or binomial regression based on my data distribution?

Tags: r, logistic, multiple-regression, ggplot2

In the attached image, the x-axis is the proportion of children at a school who passed at least 5 GCSE exams that year, and the y-axis is a count of the schools. The different colours are whether the school is in a rural or urban area.

I want to do a regression to see how the school being in a rural vs. urban area affects this measure of attainment: 5_GCSEs ~ rural.

I've read that if your dependent variable is a proportion (as mine is), it can be advisable to convert this into a count of successes out of the total number of trials (i.e. # pupils obtaining 5 GCSEs / # pupils sitting GCSEs) for each school and run a binomial logistic regression. However, you need to look at the data distribution first to determine if this is necessary.

[image: histogram]

This looks quite normally distributed other than the second small peak around 1. Does this mean I can just use linear regression?

I've also attached the residual plots and QQ plots. However, as the only independent variable is binary, I'm unsure how to interpret these.

[image: residual plot]

[image: QQ plot]

Grateful for any suggestions about what the distribution of my data suggests about the type of regression analysis I should do.

Comment: You didn't attach any plots. However, they would be irrelevant to the question as no regression model makes assumptions about the marginal distribution, only the conditional distribution.

Comment: Thanks Tim. The only way I can think to represent the conditional distribution would be in a boxplot? Do you know what features I would be looking for there to decide whether to run linear or binomial logistic?

Comment: First, I would not dichotomize the number of GCSEs passed. I would use it as a count and do a count regression (probably negative binomial).

Second, for proportions, I like beta regression.

Comment: @PeterFlom But what if the original numerators and denominators that give the proportions are available?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have data on the number of GCSEs passed. The only data I have access to is aggregated to that level of % pupils passing at least 5 GCSEs. And I also have data on the number of pupils taking GCSEs at each school. So I can work out the number of successes/number of trials for that binary variable, but cannot do a straightforward count of number of GCSEs unfortunately. Based on your suggestions, I think I will try running a beta regression

Comment: Beta regression is *ad hoc* and would be difficult to justify unless all the schools have similar numbers of children.  A GLM based on a count response would be a better initial choice.

Comment: This question is related, probably the same data (duplicate?):  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/623913/can-i-use-quasi-binomial-regression-on-proportion-data-in-this-way