# Can I use quasi-binomial regression on proportion data in this way?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, proportion, quasi-likelihood

`prop.pass` = proportion of students who passed the exam
`num` = number of students who sat the exam
`urban` = if school is in urban area (1 = urban, 0 = rural)
`%dis` = % pupils at school defined as "disadvantaged" (by parental income). Students either are or aren't disadvantaged.

Is the following regression suitable to determine if there is a difference in the rural and urban exam pass rate, controlling for %dis?

```r
glm(prop.pass ~ urban + %dis, weights = num, family = quasibinomial, 
    data = exam_df)
```

Secondly, I get the output:

```r
Coefficients:
  (Intercept)         urban          %dis  
       3.5123        -0.1244        -0.8605  

Degrees of Freedom: 3156 Total (i.e. Null);  3154 Residual
  (73 observations deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      55930 
Residual Deviance: 27650    AIC: NA
```

Do I interpret this as being from an urban rather than rural area is associated  with an decrease in the log odds of passing the exam of 0.1244?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216122/what-is-the-difference-between-logistic-regression-and-fractional-response-regre